# why does tesseract not load in python

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

So i wanted to use tesseract and i installed both pytesseract and tesseract ocr and created the path. So why is it when i try to use tesseract i get an error message which says :

`1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')`

and here is my code :

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('maaan.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
print( pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng'))
```

by the way im using windows 10

please help me :(

Comment: `from PIL import Image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('maaan.jpg')))`
can you try this in terminal

Comment: its not working ,its giving me an error on the 'print'

Comment: make sure you are running program in same directory,if that doesn't work please show error

Comment: Does "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/eng.traineddata" exist?

Comment: Try with `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'` (escaped spaces)